# iPhone sdk Storing the block parameter for later use

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I have 2 classes:

Class A:

Registered as observer for `NSNotification` with name `notificationName`

.h file declares - `typedef void (^block1)(NSError *error);`

Private instance variable - `block1 _block1_obj;`

Then have 2 methods like these:

```
- (void) doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:(block1)handlerBlock
{
   _block1_obj = handlerBlock;    // Also tried _block1_obj = [handlerBlock copy];
   [classB_obj doAnotherThing];
}

- (void) notificationHandler:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   ...
   _block1_obj(error);
}
```

Class B:

```
- (void) doAnotherThing
{
   ...
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:notificationName
                                                            object:nil
                                                          userInfo:dict];
}
```

Now I found while debugging that,
`_block1_obj` is assigned a value in `doSomethingWithCompletionHandler`

But after some time when control comes in notificationHandler:
`_block1_obj` is `nil`.

Not sure why is this. Can any one please explain?

Update:
I also tried creating a property with `copy` attribute but it did not work too.

Comment: The property with copy attribute should work. Please show that code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the block from stack to heap. If is insufficint to declare a copy block if you don't use it, but assign the ivar direcrly without copy.

Comment: Yes, I know it needs to be copied to host. Thats what I tried doing using copy. But still it did not work. I also tried using property with copy attribute instead of instance variable, but of no use.

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the instance variable as `__strong`, so `ARC` will know it has to retain the object.

I would suggest you use a private property, something like this in your `.m` file:

```
@interface YourClass ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) block1 block1_obj;

@end

@implementation YourClass

@end
```

and then assign the block by using the accessor:

```
self.block1_obj = handlerBlock;
```